# How to do authentication with ASP.NET Mvc project and WebApi?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-web-api

I have a an old ASP.NET MVC project (.NET framework 4.7.2) which uses the default Identity setup with IdentityDbContext, UserManager, SignInManager etc. And the application uses CookieAuthentication.

What we want to do is create a new web api server in .NET6 and gradually port code over to this api project. The api will be using the same database, so all the users, roles, etc will be available in both projects.

So when we create new features the idea is that the MVC project will forward the request to the web api server to complete the job.

But we're not sure how to go about with authentication. Currently I've setup the web api with JWT and done testing via postman, and this works fine, but I'm not sure how this would be done when the request is coming from another web server (the mvc project).

And since IdentityServer is no longer free to use I don't really know where to look.

Would be nice if someone could point us in the right direction :)

Comment: Are they both on the same domain?

Comment: @ekke Yes, they will be on the same domain.